# Does centrifuging and filtering supernatant confer an advantage compared to just filtering?

Tags: microbiology, centrifugation, bacteriophage

We are trying to isolate bacteriophages from environmental soil samples. One of the first steps is elution, centrifugation and filtering of the soil samples.

[One protocol](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7014677/) suggests to:

1. Elute the soil 1:1 with buffer solution. (e.g. [Phosphate buffered saline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphate-buffered_saline))
2. Manually shake the tube a few times.
3. Let it settle overnight at 4°C
4. Centrifuge 3x 10 min, 5000g at 4°C
5. Prefilter supernatant with 16 um cellulose
6. Filter with 0.22 um PES filter

The suspended soil will settle somewhat overnight. In the paper they state:

> In this optimization protocol, any filtration attempt with pore size < 16 μm was impaired if the single (Fig. ​(Fig.1,1, route 1–4) or united (Fig. 1, route 5–6) supernatants were not centrifuged thrice at 5000×g for 10 min beforehand.

When we do this same protocol, we find that in most samples the supernatant can be pushed through a 0.22 um syringe filter  without clogging even before centrifuging. Since centrifuging does take a while when processing many samples, we are considering skipping this step.

Now, is the purpose of centrifuging the eluted sample solely to make filtration easier or are there any other advantages to centrifuging when attempting to isolate bacteriophages?

Comment: This is the sort of thing you need to use your own common sense for. You have soil you want to get rid of. Centrifugation will do that efficiently and in bulk. But perhaps it is a problem in the field, and in any case you need to filter smaller particles. If you can kill two birds with one stone, fine. If clogged membranes are a pain, not fine. That’s my take, knowing nothing about isolating phage. But I’d try what was most convenient and see if it worked. The main thing is to think about what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having read up on this subject and successfully isolated phages from soil I can say fairly confidently that **centrifugation can be skipped** unless the sample is very dirty and clogs the filter.

For example, [here](https://phagesdb.org/media/workflow/protocols/pdfs/Collecting__Screening_Soil_Samples_6.2013_PDF_1.pdf) is a direct isolation protocol from soil that does not use centrifugation but lets the sediment settle for 10 minutes before filtering the supernatant.